# Unable to connect to Azure SQL from within Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, sails.js, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

I have just deployed a web app in Node.js to Azure which seems to be unable to connect to an Azure SQL Server in the same region.

I checked for the following:

- SQL server firewall: I enabled access to Azure services (and for good measure, the web app IPs too)
- Web logs: nothing, the server works fine, but anything that involves a query times out without any error at all
- Local deployment: running the app locally (`node app.js`) works out of the box

The app uses Sails.js, and the `sails-mssql` adapter.

EDIT: I have also tried with a dummy app that connects to the db and upon a succesful row retrieval (`Table.findOne().then()`) returns a response. The first time, it works (albeit with 30 sec latency). After that, it's just a timeout when loading the page, or an error 502.

EDIT 2: It would seem that `sails-sqlserver` is the culprit, it bundles a version of `mssql` known to be incompatible with Azure SQL v12 (see [here](https://github.com/pekim/tedious/releases/tag/v1.12.3)). I forced an update via `npm-shrinkwrap` to `mssql` 2.3.1, but it still does not work.

What else can I check for issues? I'm out of ideas.

Comment: What is the error that you are receiving?

Comment: It is important to note the difference between Azure SQL Database (ASQL) and Azure SQL Server (on a VM). First thing I would check is diagnostic page for your ASQL (if it is ASQL).

Comment: @JosephIdziorek No error, just a timeout when retrieving a page involving DB access. No errors on logs.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to connect via SQL Management Studio? Just to rule out any weird connections. Are you able to create a table etc..
If you dont have the management studio you can connect via Visual Studio.

Is this a VM or a SQL DB? VM...did you open endpoints? SQL DB..can you create tables via the management portal?

I never used sails but here is an example of using msnodesql and see if it connects. could be an issue with just sails

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-develop-nodejs-simple-windows/

Comment: It's a SQL DB (no VMs involved). The app runs in a Web App container. About SQL Management Studio, I can connect successfully to the database with VS2015, and when the app is running locally.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it may occur 502 error because the node.js process is crashing and the front end is left with a request and returning a 502.

You can run your application on local and monitor the logs of sails process to check what crashed the process.

Also, if it only occurs on Azure, you can leverage the logstream tool on the Kudu console of your site to monitor the log of the site. The URL of the tool should be like:
`https://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/logstream`

Comment: Just tried your suggestion. Local sails run does not crash, it just works (tm). Azure run times out, and logstream does not show anything. Requests to the test endpoint do not show up at all.

Comment: If you difficult in opening log stream page, you also can download log files. Login Kudu console of your site, click the Diagnostic dump button under tool section on top navigation. Or `https://<your_site_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/dump`

Comment: Please see edit above regarding `sails-sqlserver`'s usage of outdated libraries.